# How to disable UIPickerView (Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Is there a way to make the UIPickerView read-only? This means that the user cannot flip through the options.

PS. This is not the same as not passing anything in the `didSelectRow` method because I only want the user to see that the picker is there and not to touch it.

Comment: For the Swift version, see [How to disable UIPickerView (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41796806/2745495).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set the picker's `userInteractionEnabled` to NO.

Answer (score 26):

Use this to make it not interactable

```
[pickerObj setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

and this to

```
[pickerObj setAlpha:.6];
```

fade the opacity so it looks non-interactable

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `UIPickerView` associated with a `UITextField`, just set the text field's `isEnabled` property to `false`.