# Xcode Disable Picker After Fade

Tags: xcode, hide, picker

How can I disable a UIPicker in xcode? I have tried:

```
piker.enabled = NO;
```

and

```
picker.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But they just dont seem to work. How could I disable a UIPicker, without removing them from the SubView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIPickerView inherits from UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html), [which has a "`userInteractionEnabled`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled), so doing "`picker.userInteractionEnabled = NO`" should *certainly* work.

You should make certain that "`picker`" is a valid IBOutlet and is connected to the actual picker.

Also, to indicate to the user that the picker is disabled, [set the alpha of it to some fraction, e.g. "`[picker setAlpha: 0.6f];`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377692/disable-uipickerview)

Comment: Okay thanks. It is still not working for some reason. So I will try it again some other time. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: is picker a valid IBOutlet? If you do "`if (picker == NULL) NSLog(@"why is my picker null?");`" right before you try to disable it, does the NSLog ***not*** print?

Comment: Yeah if i place that code right before I try to disable it, the NSLog does not show up.