# react-native: disable PickerIOS element

Tags: ios, react-native

I do not know how to disable the user from interacting with a `PickerIOS` using `react-native`, and there does not seem to be much documentation about it out there. 
More importantly, I only need it to be disabled or not when the element is initially rendered.

A possible solution would be to use a `<Text>` instead, like so:

```
{isDisabled? <Text>{...}</Text> : <PickerIOS>{...}</PickerIOS>}
```

but maybe there's a simpler way out there. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you use `this.state.isDisabled` this seems like a perfectly fine solution.

`{this.state.isDisabled ? <Text>{...}</Text> : <PickerIOS>{...}</PickerIOS> }`

along with..

`this.setState({isDisabled:true})`

Comment: yup, I agree, for my use case this looks very clean. On the other hand, it is weird that you cannot disable a PickerIOS component. Maybe I should ask for it as a feature?

Comment: You might be able to use setNativeProps along with setUserInteractionEnabled and setAlpha - see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377692/disable-uipickerview