# How to disable UIPickerView (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I would like to disable the UIPickerView, but setting it to "isEnabled = false" does not work. And no, I don't want to disable the view while using it, but instead not being able to scroll through the view until a certain action is done for it to be re-enabled.

The code I tried here doesn't work (it may not even be swift code):   [How to disable UIPickerView (Objective-C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377692/disable-uipickerview#)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To disable user input, use:

```
myPickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Then, to re-enable user input, use:

```
myPickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

From the Apple Documentation Page on [.isUserInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled):

> When set to *false*, user events—such as touch and keyboard—intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event queue. When set to *true*, events are delivered to the view normally.

Comment: Do you know how to change the UIPickerView to grey if UserInteractionEnabled is set to false?

Comment: Just toggle between `myPickerView.alpha = 1` (Normal) and `myPickerView.alpha = 0.5` (Grayed-out). Note that you can change the 0.5 to your desired alpha value

Comment: Setting the **getter** `isUserInteractionEnabled` does not work.
Instead you can use the property `userInteractionEnabled`.

Comment: "*Setting the getter isUserInteractionEnabled does not work.*" It does work. The [`userInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled?language=objc) is for the Obj-C version. For Swift, [`isUserInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled) has both a getter and a setter.